# Windows installed on second partition, how to add it to boot menu?

Tags: windows, debian, grub, debian-squeeze

I'm using Debian 6.0.6 Squeeze at the moment, I installed it over Windows XP.

It's just one hard drive where I first installed Windows XP and than used some Windows tool to make partition where I later installed Debian

Now, I can easily boot in Debian but there is no sign of Windows. I tried few things recommended on line, but still I couldn't get it working

I tried `os-prober`, tried to edit `grub.cfg` (I managed to add Windows XP to menu but this is just empty link, when I enter nothing happens (blank screen), where should it link to?)

---

also this, after fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 40.0 GB, 40020664320 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4865 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c0014

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               2        4663    37447484+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda2            4664        4864     1614532+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda5               2        2032    16313976    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda6            2033        4663    21133476   83  Linux
```

---

update-grub

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-686
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-686
done
```

Comment: Looking for Bootloader isn't quite what you're looking for, eh?

Comment: i'm not sure, do you mean tweaking bios? maybe I need to link to some file which windows uses to boot, don't know

Comment: You need to create a chainloader entry.

Comment: @TomWijsman, `update-grub` should take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

From the previous answer I gathered, that you are probably using grub2. The correct way to manually add a menu entry is through the `/etc/grub.d/` directory.

Create a file `01_windows_xp` (change the number according to the ordering you want, linux got the `10_`) and add the following to it:

```
echo "Adding Windows XP to the Menu..."
cat << EOF
menuentry "Windows XP"
        set root=(hd0,5)
        chainloader +1
}
EOF
```

Then rerun `update-grub`. You can look at the generated `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` afterwards. This way the new menu entry will survive a kernel update, where update-grub will be run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did not overwrite your windows installation (you said you installed "over" windows XP?), the following commands should be enough. If not, please update your question with their output:

```
sudo update-grub
Sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Comment: xp is alive on partition for sure, thanks for reply, I will try this

Comment: still not showing up, I updated question with more infos, any help appreciated :)

Comment: @zarkoz, could you post the output of the `update-grub` command? Does it detect windows?

Comment: tried that few times before, doesn't help

Comment: /dev/sda5               2        2032    16313976    7  HPFS/NTFS -- this is your Windows installation. change your grub manually adding sda5 with a chainloader, then, `sudo update-grub` and  `Sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

Comment: how to manually change grub, which file would this be?

Comment: /boot/grub/menu.lst . you need to edit this using your preferred text editor with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

edit your /boot/grub/menu.lst using your preferred text editor with sudo.
add the lines:

```
title Microsoft Windows XP
root (hd0,5)
chainloader +1
```

run:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

reboot & done

**if using grub2:**

the configuration file is located here:

```
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and the lines added should be:

```
menuentry "Microsoft Windows XP" {
set root=(hd0,5)
chainloader +1
}
```

run:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Comment: menu.lst doesn't exist, I created it, paste the code, update and install, reboot, still nothing :(

Comment: @zarkoz you are probably using grub2. i updated my answer.

Comment: still no dice. I noticed that whenever I run update-grub, grub.cfg restores changes, like i didn't write anything in this file

Comment: try not doing `update-grub` then. add it using `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and reboot.

Comment: Microsoft Windows xp shows up, but when I enter it's just blank screen  with cursor blinking

Comment: thats weird. try changing `set root=(hd0,5)` to `set root=(hd0,1)` . sda1 seems to be an extended partition but well, at least we try all possibilities. im running out of juice here.

Comment: still nothing, I will keep trying, thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: you got some serious strange things going on there mate. well, either that or my eyes are drunk (yes my eyes not me). hope you get it sorted out.